# How to create a range input that accepts pixels?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a range input for pixels. Something similar to:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("change", () => {
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="5px" max="50px">
```

However, it does not understand pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range inputs only support numbers, short of implementing your own UI with a mass of JS you aren't going to get it to put the letters `px` on the value.

Add them yourself when you read it.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("change", () => {
  console.log(`${input.value}px`);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="5" max="50">
```